# Why should users be allowed to edit cart items directly in the order review step?

Tags: user-expectation, e-commerce

The task of going back a few steps in the checkout process to edit a section within the cart is observed to be a cumbersome process. What evidence exists around why allowing the user to edit their cart in one step - not going back to a previous screen - is the best user experience?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a product/plugin/gadget demand

Answer (score 1):

If you search on tips and advance on Customer Conversion and Checkout Optimisation, you'll find that there is a lot of focus on creating a very simple and frictionless experience.

For example, look at the Conversation Rate Optimzation [Checkout Experience](https://www.shopify.com.au/blog/120261189-conversion-rate-optimization#checkout) suggested by Shopify:

> The checkout experience is one the final steps of every customer’s purchasing process, so it needs to be as frictionless and flawless as possible to avoid having frustrated customers abandon their carts at the last moment.

> At this point in their journey, your customers display clear intent to make a purchase. You need to make that purchase happen quickly and conveniently without any stress or confusion.

Generally the rule of thumb would be to try and make the user experience as simple and easy as possible, so instead of asking why users should be allowed to do something that would be easier for them, you should ask why users shouldn't be allowed to edit cart items directly in the order review step.